# Spring Boot with @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

If I need to ignore the serialization/deserialization from one field I put the `@JsonIgnore` on that field:

```
@JsonIgnore
private String name;
```

But if I only need in serialization or only in deserealization I put in getter or setter method.

but it`s possible to use in some method? If my user call:

```
http://myApp/public/user/1
```

I need to ignore the properties pass for example, but if my user call:

```
http://myApp/private/user/1
```

I don't need to ignore the properties pass

Is it possible?

Comment: You can create 2 different Response objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Json Filter with a `FilterProvider`

1. you use [`@JsonFilter`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFilter.html) annotation to assign a filter name to your POJO.
2. before serialization, you attach an instance of [`SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html) to the filter name.  the class has two factory methods for filters that work based on propertry names.

Here is an example of the annotation declaration:

```
@JsonFilter("filterByName")
public class So {
    public String alwaysWrite = "alwaysWriteValue";
    public String somtimeIgnore = "somtimeIgnoreValue";
}
```

here is a method that assignes a filter that will ignore `somtimeIgnore` property

```
public void dontWriteSomtimes(So so) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()  
      .addFilter("filterByName", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("somtimeIgnore"));  
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);  
    try {
        System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(so));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:
`{"alwaysWrite":"alwaysWriteValue"}`

here is a method that will write everything: just assign a non-existent or empty property:

```
public void writeEveryting(So so) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()  
      .addFilter("filterByName", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(""));  
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);  
    try {
        System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(so));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:
`{"alwaysWrite":"alwaysWriteValue","somtimeIgnore":"somtimeIgnoreValue"}`